# Accessing parent scope/controller from same-directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Nutshell:

```
<layout direction="horizontal"> <!--ParentX -->
    <layout>ChildA</layout>
    <layout>ChildB</layout>
    <layout direction="vertical"> <!--ParentY -->
        <layout>ChildC</layout>
        <layout>ChildD</layout>
    </layout>
</layout>
```

How can I know ParentY's direction from ChildC link-function?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nOr1Q6TxQi03ODRK9Jph?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried $scope.$parent?

Comment: @apohl, sorry for offline. Is there any way to guarantee that $scope.$parent will be instance of Layout?

Comment: It depends on where you call it from. If from ChildC, yes. You could always do a check to make sure.

Comment: @apohl Could you give me a hand? No idea which approach I should choose. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nOr1Q6TxQi03ODRK9Jph?p=preview) template is ready

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to do. Why are the parent elements directives?

Comment: @apohl If parent Layout is directed (direction === vertical || horizontal) child(no matter directed or not) has to append another div for splitting.